List of timestamps, group by how many per hour
I have a json list of timestamps:
[
  "2024-03-27 00:30:30.321000",
  "2024-03-27 00:34:58.695000",
  "2024-03-27 00:37:38.352000",
  "2024-03-27 00:37:40.419000",
  "2024-03-27 00:43:54.536000",
  "2024-03-27 00:49:39.231000",
  "2024-03-27 01:03:39.637000",
  "2024-03-27 01:05:24.370000",
  "2024-03-27 01:17:43.586000",
  "2024-03-27 01:17:47.447000",
  "2024-03-27 01:17:59.913000",
  "2024-03-27 01:18:34.872000",
  "2024-03-27 01:18:36.922000",
  "2024-03-27 01:18:44.626000",
  "2024-03-27 01:19:11.057000",
  "2024-03-27 01:19:12.307000",
  "2024-03-27 01:21:11.322000",
  "2024-03-27 01:26:54.640000",
  "2024-03-27 01:26:55.055000",
  ...

I am looking to plot the frequency of them, for example per hour. I could get this to work with pandas, but that required me to add a dummy column:
[
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "ts": "2024-03-27 00:24:13.132000"
  },
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "ts": "2024-03-27 00:30:30.321000"
  },
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "ts": "2024-03-27 00:34:58.695000"
  },
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "ts": "2024-03-27 00:36:04.166000"
  },
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "ts": "2024-03-27 00:37:38.352000"
  },
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "ts": "2024-03-27 00:37:40.419000"
  },
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "ts": "2024-03-27 00:43:54.536000"
  },
 ....
]

So I could use sum():
import sys
import pandas as pd

freq = '1d'
df = pd.read_json(sys.stdin)
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
overview = df.resample(freq, on='ts').foo.sum()
print(overview)

This gave what I am looking for:
2024-03-27      674
2024-03-28      405
2024-03-29      366
2024-03-30      352
2024-03-31      541
2024-04-01      657
2024-04-02      398
2024-04-03      523
2024-04-04      466
2024-04-05      498
2024-04-06      468
2024-04-07      312
2024-04-08      453
2024-04-09      625
2024-04-10      654
2024-04-11      696
2024-04-12      624
2024-04-13      377
2024-04-14      304
2024-04-15      493
2024-04-16      544
2024-04-17      526

Can I do this without the dummy column? So just with the simple list of timestamps as input?

Working with your sample data you could use :
freq = '1h'
data = [
  "2024-03-27 00:30:30.321000",
  "2024-03-27 00:34:58.695000",
  "2024-03-27 00:37:38.352000",
  "2024-03-27 00:37:40.419000",
  "2024-03-27 00:43:54.536000",
  "2024-03-27 00:49:39.231000",
  "2024-03-27 01:03:39.637000",
  "2024-03-27 01:05:24.370000",
  "2024-03-27 01:17:43.586000",
  "2024-03-27 01:17:47.447000",
  "2024-03-27 01:17:59.913000",
  "2024-03-27 01:18:34.872000",
  "2024-03-27 01:18:36.922000",
  "2024-03-27 01:18:44.626000",
  "2024-03-27 01:19:11.057000",
  "2024-03-27 01:19:12.307000",
  "2024-03-27 01:21:11.322000",
  "2024-03-27 01:26:54.640000",
  "2024-03-27 01:26:55.055000"]

df = pd.Series(data=pd.to_datetime(data))
overview = df.groupby([df.dt.floor(freq)]).count()
print(overview )

The code yields :
# with freq = 1h
2024-03-27 00:00:00     6
2024-03-27 01:00:00    13
# with freq = 1d
2024-03-27    19


IIUC, you could use resample.size, you won't need the dummy "foo" column:
df.resample(freq, on='ts').size()

Example:
lst = [
  "2024-03-27 00:30:30.321000",
  "2024-03-27 00:34:58.695000",
  "2024-03-27 00:37:38.352000",
  "2024-03-28 01:26:54.640000",
  "2024-03-28 01:26:55.055000",
]
freq = '1d'
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': lst})
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])

df.resample(freq, on='ts').size()

ts
2024-03-27    3
2024-03-28    2
Freq: D, dtype: int64


The two answers above lead me in to right direction. Eventually it can be done with just two lines:
df = pd.read_json(sys.stdin, typ='series')
overview = df.groupby([df.dt.floor(freq)]).count()

